# Read Socket Packets correctly from Sb0t Chat Server with Java

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

My question is about Java. I am trying to receive a package called MSG_CHAT_SERVER_PUBLIC from a chat server. This package contains the user's name and the message that he sends.
The protocol is in this list of protocols: http://uruguayos-xtremos2011.blogspot.com/p/ares-protocol-aresnuevo.html?m=1
In the Public method you can see how the server forms the package: https://github.com/AresChat/sb0t/blob/128b2755cdfedaf498d66fbcdf9fda010f4d3087/core/TCPOutbound.cs

In the Service method you can see how a chat client receives the packets: https://github.com/AresChat/cb0t/blob/master/cb0t/RoomPanel/AresSocket.cs
In the Eval_Public method you can see how the package is read in the Chat Client: https://github.com/AresChat/cb0t/blob/master/cb0t/RoomPanel/Room.Handler.cs

I have the following as code (but no read package appears in the EditText; I expect the opposite):

```
InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();

                        while (sock.isConnected()) {

                            //  get message length, first 2 bytes
                            byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[2];
                            in.read(lengthBytes);
                            // convert to int
                            int messageLength = lengthBytes[0] << 8 | lengthBytes[1];


                            // get the protocol byte
                            int procotol = in.read();

                            // get message, length bytes
                            byte[] messageBytes = new byte[messageLength];
                            s.chat.append(Integer.toString(in.read(messageBytes)));


                            // separate message, first x bytes are username
                            int length = 0;

                            // get username length
                            for (byte messageByte : messageBytes) {
                                if (messageByte == 0) break;
                                length++;
                            }

                            // extract username
                            byte[] username = new byte[length];
                            System.arraycopy(messageBytes, 0, username, 0, length);

                            int pos = length + 1;

                            // message length
                            length = messageBytes.length - pos;


                            // extract message
                            byte[] message = new byte[length];
                            System.arraycopy(messageBytes, pos, message, 0, length);

                            s.chat.append("message length: " + messageLength + "\nprocotol: " + procotol + "\nusername: " + new String(username) + "\nmessage: " + new String(message));


                        }
```

Maybe it will be easier for you if I tell you what I've made so far: https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2GIBqaxDQCgTZ_PCnapHpoRjny

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `in.read(messageBytes);` Check how many bytes are actually read: `int nread = in.read(messageBytes);`. And make a loop to read all if less.

Comment: @blackapps I edited the code and did try to print the number of bytes in the EdittText. But nothing appears...  Was that what you meant?

Comment: You cannot update the gui while executing internet code in a thread. Your app eill crash. You better log the value and also the size of the buffer and compare.

Comment: @blackapps But the app don't crash. And there's is also no exception in Logcat...